# Thread pool in Qt 4.3

Tags: qt

Is there some way to use thread pool with Qt 4.3? I know it has now been implemented in Qt 4.5. But is it somehow available in Qt 4.3 also?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the first version of QtConcurrent from the [**Qt Labs**](http://labs.trolltech.com/page/Projects/Threads/QtConcurrent) project. This version of QtConcurrent is compatible with Qt4.2 but 4.3 is recommended .

> From Qt Labs ...
>   [Qt Concurrent](http://labs.trolltech.com/page/Projects/Threads/QtConcurrent)
>
> Platforms:     Windows, Linux, Mac Qt
>   version:   4.2 required, 4.3
>   recommended.   
>   Qt Concurrent is a C++
>   template library for writing
>   multi-threaded applications. 
> Qt
>   Concurrent provides high-level APIs
>   that makes it possible to write
>   multi-threaded programs withouth using
>   low-level threading primitives such as
>   critcal sections, mutexes or wait
>   conditions. 
> Programs written with Qt
>   Concurrent automaticallly adjust the
>   number of threads used according to
>   the number of processor cores
>   available. This means that
>   applications written today will
>   continue to scale when deployed on
>   multi-core systems in the future. 
> The
>   library includes functional
>   programming style APIs for for
>   parallel list prosessing, a MapReduce
>   implementation for shared-memory
>   (non-distributed) systems, and classes
>   for managing asynchronous computations
>   in GUI applications. 
> The code can be
>   checked out with subversion: svn
>   checkout
>   svn://labs.trolltech.com/svn/threads/qtconcurrent
>   qtconcurrent 
>  If you don't have svn,
>   you can [download a package](http://labs.trolltech.com/images/5/57/Qtconcurrent-0.1.2.zip) instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the 4.5 source code and rip it out from there. If they use their own API, it should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use straight [pthreads](http://cs.pub.ro/~apc/2003/resources/pthreads/uguide/document.htm) API in C/C++ with QT and implement your own thread pool.

Although you are probably looking for a solution involving less amount of work.

Comment: I already have a thread pool implemented in my code. I wanted to know,if Qt has something for it.